# Delphi RegExp регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi

Пытаюсь вытащить из текста нужные мне параметры, а именно из адреса вконтакте
https://vk.com/video-17781368_166558880?hash=b9c638d13c911163
нужно вытащить три значения  17781368, 166558880 и b9c638d13c911163 пробовал делать вот так:

```
   RegExp := TRegExpr.Create;
   RegExp.InputString :=URL;
   RegExp2 := TRegExpr.Create;
   RegExp2.InputString :=text;
   RegExp.Expression := 'vk.com/video-(.*?)_(.*?)?hash=(.*?)';
```

В итоге первая переменная находится нормально, вторая находится, вот только еще в конце остается символ вопроса "166558880?" третий параметр пуст. 
Пробовал экранироваться знак вопроса

```
   RegExp.Expression := 'vk.com/video-(.*?)_(.*?)\?hash=(.*?)';
```

Первые два параметра находит нормально, третий все равно пуст. Что делаю не так, может не правильно экранирую, в Делфи с регулярками раньше не работал может где натупил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше так:

```
'vk.com/video-(\d+)_(\d+)\?hash=(\w+)'
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/M7qB4N)

Comment: спасибо, работает